# KQL (azure monitor) I wanted a chart that dynamically tracks the 5 logs with the highest consumption and track that consumption by day

Tags: kql

We have had issue tracking and alerting if our logging starts to consume too much resource and in realty incurred to much cost

Now Ive got it working but I am sure there is a better solution

```
let TWmonthEnd = endofmonth(datetime(now),-2); 
let twoweek =ago(14d);

let histbase=Usage
| where TimeGenerated > TWmonthEnd 
| project TimeGenerated, DataType, Solution, Quantity, IsBillable
| where IsBillable =='True'
| summarize TWmonthEnd = sumif(Quantity, TimeGenerated >TWmonthEnd)
            by DataType;

let hisresults=histbase
|top 5 by TWmonthEnd
|project DataType;

let currentresult = Usage
| where TimeGenerated > twoweek 
| project TimeGenerated, DataType, Solution, Quantity, IsBillable
| where IsBillable =='True'
| summarize weekly = sum(Quantity) by bin(TimeGenerated,1d), DataType;

currentresult
| join kind = inner hisresults on DataType
|where TimeGenerated > twoweek 
| project TimeGenerated, DataType, weekly
| sort by TimeGenerated
```

PS Yes I know I could have just hardcoded the logs (as there are not that many) but I belive code should be dynamic and not need tinkering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem like you are very nearly there and looks sensible enough to me.  One thing I would probably suggest though, is instead of looking at the top hitters over a long period I'd probably look at top hitters over more granular periods.

For instance show me everything which generates most cost per day over x days and report on all of those over the month.  That way you should hopefully spot any outliers easier.

```
let TWmonthEnd = endofmonth(datetime(now),-2); 
let twoweek =ago(14d);
let AnyTop5Usage = Usage //Grab all top 5 hits per day and offer these for monitoring
| where TimeGenerated > (TWmonthEnd)
| where _IsBillable == true
| summarize sum(_BilledSize) by DataType, floor(TimeGenerated, 1d)
| partition by TimeGenerated (top 5 by sum__BilledSize)
| summarize make_set(DataType);
Usage //Show last two weeks of usage
| where TimeGenerated >= floor((twoweek), 1d)
| where _IsBillable == true
| where DataType in (AnyTop5Usage)
| summarize daily = sum(Quantity) by floor(TimeGenerated, 1d), DataType
| sort by TimeGenerated asc
//| render timechart
```

| TimeGenerated | daily | DataType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-26T00:00:00.0000000Z | 0.004116 | ProtectionStatus |
| 2023-09-26T00:00:00.0000000Z | 0.20706 | Heartbeat |
| 2023-09-26T00:00:00.0000000Z | 0.0044800000000000009 | Operation |
| 2023-09-26T00:00:00.0000000Z | 0.29616800000000007 | AzureMetrics |
| 2023-09-26T00:00:00.0000000Z | 0.17425900000000003 | StorageBlobLogs |
| 2023-09-26T00:00:00.0000000Z | 0.568918 | webhost_test_CL |
| 2023-09-27T00:00:00.0000000Z | 1.117705 | AzureMetrics |
| 2023-09-27T00:00:00.0000000Z | 0.842693 | StorageBlobLogs |
| 2023-09-27T00:00:00.0000000Z | 0.014112 | ProtectionStatus |
| 2023-09-27T00:00:00.0000000Z | 0.70992 | Heartbeat |

*All data, I don't generate enough Billed Data in my own Log Analytics to show anything meaningful as demo output.